# Save in Two Models with post_save

Tags: python, django, signals

I Have an problem :

Exists 3 models in my app:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    #fields here ...

class Imovel(models.Model):
    #more fields and..
    dono = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)

class Captacao(models.Model):
    #here, have the fields of others models (Cliente and Imovel)
```

I Want populate the models "Cliente" and "Imovel" through of model "Captacao"... i know there post_save for this, but I do not know how to do this, save those fields in each respective model.

Thanks,

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. What does "have the fields of other models" mean? How is Captacao related to Imovel and Cliente?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have the Cliente yet, you can create him, using the Imovel data:

```
def save_in_other_models(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.create(
        name=instance.name,
        ident=instance.ident,
    )
    Imovel.objects.create(
        dono=cliente
    )

models.signals.post_save.connect(save_in_other_models, sender=Captacao)
```

---------------- ** ---------------- ** ---------------- ** ---------------- ** ---------------- ** ---------------- ** ---------

If you already have the Cliente instance in the relation with your Captacao:

** and this will create a new Imovel using the Cliente relation with you Imovel

```
def save_in_other_models(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Imovel.objects.create(
        dono=instance.cliente
    )

models.signals.post_save.connect(save_in_other_models, sender=Captacao)
```